# How to remove the transparent border in Office 2013 or later?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

Starting in Office 2013, Microsoft implemented a new GUI architecture, and Office doesn't respect the theme or personalization settings of the OS.  I don't like it, and it causes problems for me quite frequently (the code, not the visuals).  It caused problems when I used 2013, and over the years, I've started to figure out parts of the problems.

One of the problems is the transparent border around the window.  **How do I turn this off?**

I usually run windows using the "classic theme", which disables almost all transparency effects.  I use Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 10 Enterprise.

The transparent border is ***outside of the regular window***, so if I want to resize the window, I don't click on the border, like I do with every other window, I have to click ***outside the window***.  This is a problem in and of itself, because when I try to adjust the window size, I frequently wind up clicking on the window behind the window I am trying to adjust.

This [forum post](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/372117-office-2016-how-do-i-remove-the-black-edge-around-the-main-windows/) is related to the phenomenon, and probably two VDI technologies fighting each other.  However, I already disable hardware acceleration when I install Office.

Comment: What's the transparent border you mentioned? Would you mind to share  a picture about it.

Comment: @winnil how does one take a picture of something that is invisible?